# Clear form field after select for jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

We're using JQuery UI Autocomplete and I'm having problems clearing the textbox containing the search term once the query is complete.  Here is our JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("form#search input#term").autocomplete({
            source: '<%= Url.Action("Display", "Search") %>',
            delay: 200,
            minLength: 3,
            parse: function (data) {
                var array = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    array[array.length] = { data: data[i], value: data[i], result: data[i].link };
                }
                return array;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                window.location.href = ui.item.value;
                $(this).val() = "";
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

This code works fine in Firefox, but IE 8 is throwing an exception and gives a dialog asking if I want to use the IE Script Debugger.  I saw this Stack Overflow post: [Clear form field after select for jQuery UI Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561903/clear-form-field-after-select-for-jquery-ui-autocomplete) which says the solution to the problem is to return false from the JQuery select function, but that didn't help.  Anyone have suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I don't believe this is the official jQueryUI autocomplete plugin (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) because of the `parse` option. Is this the case? If so, your question should probably link to the correct plugin.

Comment: @Andrew, Thanks for the comment, but I think it is the official JQueryUI.  We downloaded the file named jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js file from the JQuery UI site.  This file is a bit dated, the current release is jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js, which I've downloaded also, tried it with latest version of JQuery, and then Autocomplete doesn't work for me at all .

Comment: Well, there's no `parse` option on the jQueryUI widget (as far as I know). Functionality that you expect to come from that option might be causing you some issues (kind of a long shot I know).

Comment: @Andrew - OK, Thanks, I'll see what I can find about the parse option, maybe it is the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've found to fix this problem was to use the old JQuery 1.4.1 dll along with the new JQuery UI dll, version 1.8.11, I think there is a but in the JQuery dll after version 1.4.1 causing this problem.  If so, maybe a future version will fix it.

Comment: Using jQuery 1.8.2 and jqueryUI 1.9.0 the `event.preventDefault()` trick mentioned in the most upvoted answer did the magic for me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5648954/1063730

Answer (score 10):

Using Jquery 1.5.1 and JQuery-ui 1.8.10, the following works for me:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault() // <===
                window.location.href = ui.item.value;
                $(this).val('');                
            }
```

Comment: Yep its the `PreventDefault` that does the trick here... I would love to know what it's 'supposed' to bubble up to though.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).val('');
```

instead of

```
$(this).val() = "";
```

Comment: Thanks - I should have mentioned that I already tried that prior to the post and the result was the same.

Comment: Weirdly this worked for me, I don't know how `val()` works but it's obviously not as simple as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me...

```
jQuery('.SELECETOR'). autocomplete({
   ....
   ....
}).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {
               jQuery(this).val('');
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
jQuery('.SELECTOR'). autocomplete({
    // Code
}).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {
    jQuery(this).val('');
});
```